# R: Remove list type within dataframe

Tags: regex, r, list

I have list type data that is been moved in to as dataframe while though it is stored in the form of list within dataframe.

**code:** (list to dataframe )

```
O<-lapply(res, function(x) str_extract_all(x,pattern))
O
library(plyr)
maxl <- max(sapply(O,length))
out <- do.call(cbind, lapply(O,function(x) x[1:maxl]))
out <- as.data.frame(out)
```

**result:  O**

```
    $text
$text[[1]]
 [1] "qlikview" "gpa"      "access"   "gpa"      "access"   "access"   "qlikview" "gpa"      "access"  
[10] "gpa"     

$text[[2]]
 [1] "report"   "qlikview" "gpa"      "access"   "qlikview" "gpa"      "access"   "qlikview" "gpa"     
[10] "access"  

$text[[3]]
 [1] "qlikview" "gpa"      "access"   "gpa"      "access"   "access"   "qlikview" "gpa"      "access"  
[10] "gpa"     

$text[[4]]
 [1] "qlikview" "gpa"      "access"   "gpa"      "access"   "access"   "qlikview" "gpa"      "access"  
[10] "gpa"     

$text[[5]]
 [1] "report"   "qlikview" "gpa"      "access"   "access"   "gpa"      "access"   "qlikview" "gpa"     
[10] "access"   "access"   "gpa"      "qlikview" "gpa"      "access"   "qlikview" "gpa"      "access"  

$text[[6]]
 [1] "report"   "qlikview" "access"   "access"   "report"   "qlikview" "access"   "access"   "gpa"     
[10] "qlikview" "access"   "access"   "qlikview" "access"   "access"  

$text[[7]]
 [1] "report" "report" "access" "access" "report" "report" "report" "report" "report" "report" "data"  
[12] "data"   "report" "access" "report" "report"

$text[[8]]
[1] "report"   "qlikview" "gpa"      "access"   "gpa"      "access"  

$text[[9]]
 [1] "report" "gpa"    "access" "access" "gpa"    "gpa"    "gpa"    "gpa"    "gpa"    "access" "gpa"   
[12] "gpa"    "gpa"    "report"

$text[[10]]
 [1] "report" "gpa"    "gpa"    "access" "gpa"    "access" "gpa"    "access" "gpa"    "gpa"    "report"
[12] "gpa"    "gpa"    "access" "gpa"    "gpa"    "gpa"    "gpa"    "gpa"  

dput(O$text[1:10])
list(c("qlikview", "gpa", "access", "gpa", "access", "access", 
"qlikview", "gpa", "access", "gpa"), c("report", "qlikview", 
"gpa", "access", "qlikview", "gpa", "access", "qlikview", "gpa", 
"access"), c("qlikview", "gpa", "access", "gpa", "access", "access", 
"qlikview", "gpa", "access", "gpa"), c("qlikview", "gpa", "access", 
"gpa", "access", "access", "qlikview", "gpa", "access", "gpa"
), c("report", "qlikview", "gpa", "access", "access", "gpa", 
"access", "qlikview", "gpa", "access", "access", "gpa", "qlikview", 
"gpa", "access", "qlikview", "gpa", "access"), c("report", "qlikview", 
"access", "access", "report", "qlikview", "access", "access", 
"gpa", "qlikview", "access", "access", "qlikview", "access", 
"access"), c("report", "report", "access", "access", "report", 
"report", "report", "report", "report", "report", "data", "data", 
"report", "access", "report", "report"), c("report", "qlikview", 
"gpa", "access", "gpa", "access"), c("report", "gpa", "access", 
"access", "gpa", "gpa", "gpa", "gpa", "gpa", "access", "gpa", 
"gpa", "gpa", "report"), c("report", "gpa", "gpa", "access", 
"gpa", "access", "gpa", "access", "gpa", "gpa", "report", "gpa", 
"gpa", "access", "gpa", "gpa", "gpa", "gpa", "gpa"))
```

**expected result:**

```
text
1   qlikview, gpa, access, gpa, access, access, qlikview, gpa, access, gpa
2   report, qlikview, gpa, access, qlikview, gpa, access, qlikview, gpa, access
3   qlikview, gpa, access, gpa, access, access, qlikview, gpa, access, gpa
4   qlikview, gpa, access, gpa, access, access, qlikview, gpa, access, gpa
5   report, qlikview, gpa, access, access, gpa, access, qlikview, gpa, access, access, gpa, qlikview, gpa, access, qlikview, gpa, access
6   report, qlikview, access, access, report, qlikview, access, access, gpa, qlikview, access, access, qlikview, access, access
7   report, report, access, access, report, report, report, report, report, report, data, data, report, access, report, report
8   report, qlikview, gpa, access, gpa, access
```

**Can i use regular expression here to remove c("" "" "")**

Comment: Add a `paste` or `toString` somewhere in there to collapse everything into a single string?

Comment: you can try something line `noquote`.

Comment: What do you plan to do with your expected result? It looks suboptimal.

Comment: Nope i have tried all no much help !

Comment: What exactly does "upgrade ex" relate to? A `list` as a column in a `data.frame`? The "O" object that you start your question with?

Comment: I need to use this to classify later where looping into list within dataframe doesn't produce appropriate result,  my cont. question [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669721/r-building-text-classifier/29690983?noredirect=1#comment47519175_29690983)how else can i achieve this   , please guide me if you have worked on related thing

Comment: can i use `regex` instead to remove `c(" " " " " " " " )`

Comment: @Ananda Mahto it is the reproducible example for what result is given

Comment: Maybe you're looking for something like `tg$text <- sapply(tg$text, toString)`. As Roland mentioned, this looks like a suboptimal data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do this

```
library('stringr')
apply(data, 1, function(x) str_c(x$columnnane,collapse=','))
```

where, data is you dataframe and columnname is the column containing list.

---

edited answer

```
out = do.call(rbind, lapply(data, function(x) str_c(x,collapse=', ')))
```

where data is your list object

if the list is stored inside a dataframe then pass the column in place of the data above like this

```
out = do.call(rbind, lapply(data$columnname, function(x) str_c(x,collapse=', ')))
```

it will give you this. I hope this is what you are looking for!

> out
>         [,1]
>    [1,] "qlikview, gpa, access, gpa, access, access, qlikview, gpa, access, gpa"
>    [2,] "report, qlikview, gpa, access, qlikview, gpa, access, qlikview, gpa, access"
>    [3,] "qlikview, gpa, access, gpa, access, access, qlikview, gpa, access, gpa"
>    [4,] "qlikview, gpa, access, gpa, access, access, qlikview, gpa, access, gpa"
>    [5,] "report, qlikview, gpa, access, access, gpa, access, qlikview, gpa, access, access, gpa, qlikview, gpa, access, qlikview, gpa, access"
>    [6,] "report, qlikview, access, access, report, qlikview, access, access, gpa, qlikview, access, access, qlikview, access, access"
>    [7,] "report, report, access, access, report, report, report, report, report, report, data, data, report, access, report, report"
>    [8,] "report, qlikview, gpa, access, gpa, access"
>    [9,] "report, gpa, access, access, gpa, gpa, gpa, gpa, gpa, access, gpa, gpa, gpa, report"
>   [10,] "report, gpa, gpa, access, gpa, access, gpa, access, gpa, gpa, report, gpa, gpa, access, gpa, gpa, gpa, gpa, gpa"

Comment: `Error: Input to str_c should be atomic vectors`

Comment: If possible post a subset of your dataframe which is usable

Comment: Its always better to put reproducible data while you are asking a question, this will help you to get answers more quickly! Here is the post you can check out which explains how to to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: that list has been stored as dataframe , if you can see the code at begining

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75486/discussion-between-kru-and-veerendra-gadekar).

Comment: if your using `R GUI` then it works only for the list produced in question , but when you use it in `RStudio` it just gives you same list which i have given as `result (dataframe)`

Comment: now i have edited the question , please check where that is the list basically which i converted to dataframe where even i code after what i used is also given

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one

**Data**

```
dd <- list(c("qlikview", "gpa", "access", "gpa", "access", "access",
"qlikview", "gpa", "access", "gpa"), c("report", "qlikview",
"gpa", "access", "qlikview", "gpa", "access", "qlikview", "gpa",
"access"), c("qlikview", "gpa", "access", "gpa", "access", "access",
"qlikview", "gpa", "access", "gpa"), c("qlikview", "gpa", "access",
"gpa", "access", "access", "qlikview", "gpa", "access", "gpa"
), c("report", "qlikview", "gpa", "access", "access", "gpa",
"access", "qlikview", "gpa", "access", "access", "gpa", "qlikview",
"gpa", "access", "qlikview", "gpa", "access"), c("report", "qlikview",
"access", "access", "report", "qlikview", "access", "access",
"gpa", "qlikview", "access", "access", "qlikview", "access",
"access"), c("report", "report", "access", "access", "report",
"report", "report", "report", "report", "report", "data", "data",
"report", "access", "report", "report"), c("report", "qlikview",
"gpa", "access", "gpa", "access"), c("report", "gpa", "access",
"access", "gpa", "gpa", "gpa", "gpa", "gpa", "access", "gpa",
"gpa", "gpa", "report"), c("report", "gpa", "gpa", "access",
"gpa", "access", "gpa", "access", "gpa", "gpa", "report", "gpa",
                           "gpa", "access", "gpa", "gpa", "gpa", "gpa", "gpa"))
```

**Code**

```
df <- data.frame(text=rep(NA, length(dd)))
df$text <- lapply(lapply(dd, FUN = function(x) paste0(x, collapse=" ,")), FUN = noquote)
df
                                                                                                                                   text
1                                                                qlikview ,gpa ,access ,gpa ,access ,access ,qlikview ,gpa ,access ,gpa
2                                                           report ,qlikview ,gpa ,access ,qlikview ,gpa ,access ,qlikview ,gpa ,access
3                                                                qlikview ,gpa ,access ,gpa ,access ,access ,qlikview ,gpa ,access ,gpa
4                                                                qlikview ,gpa ,access ,gpa ,access ,access ,qlikview ,gpa ,access ,gpa
5  report ,qlikview ,gpa ,access ,access ,gpa ,access ,qlikview ,gpa ,access ,access ,gpa ,qlikview ,gpa ,access ,qlikview ,gpa ,access
6           report ,qlikview ,access ,access ,report ,qlikview ,access ,access ,gpa ,qlikview ,access ,access ,qlikview ,access ,access
7            report ,report ,access ,access ,report ,report ,report ,report ,report ,report ,data ,data ,report ,access ,report ,report
8                                                                                            report ,qlikview ,gpa ,access ,gpa ,access
9                                                   report ,gpa ,access ,access ,gpa ,gpa ,gpa ,gpa ,gpa ,access ,gpa ,gpa ,gpa ,report
10                      report ,gpa ,gpa ,access ,gpa ,access ,gpa ,access ,gpa ,gpa ,report ,gpa ,gpa ,access ,gpa ,gpa ,gpa ,gpa ,gpa
```

which is the desired output.

Comment: This works perfectly for a `list` but my question is list type which is in dataframe

Comment: can you `dput` your dataframe or a part of it ?

Comment: this can be used in for list , but that list can i convert into dataframe? i tried  doing this but doesn't support

Comment: why would you like to do so ?

Comment: I have to store it in dataframe for further use, if your using `R GUI` it works perfect but when same is used in `RStudio` it just gives the same list which i have given in `result (dataframe)`

Comment: @KRU you should take a look, I have updated my answer.