# Nested list in dataframe

Tags: r, nested-lists

I have used `drive_find` in the `googledrive` package to pull a list of files, and the output is a dataframe `myDocs` with 3 columns: file names, file IDs and a list of all other file properties: drive_resource.

I want to pull out the links to the documents.

At the moment I am using a for loop, like this:

```
myDocs$url <- NA
for (i in 1:nrow(myDocs)) {
  myDocs$url[i] <- myDocs$drive_resource[[i]]$webViewLink
}
```

This seems incredibly inefficient to me, but I can't find a way to use an apply function or similar to do all this in one go.

I know I can use apply functions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29694335/r-remove-list-type-within-dataframe) or `unlist` to get the whole list, but I just want to access a single element, on every row.

If it were a nested dataframe rather than a list I would use `flatten` from the `jsonlite` package and then just select the columns I wanted to keep - is there any similar function, or a smart use of apply functions etc. I can use to avoid this loop?

Comment: Can you dput(myDocs) for a working example?  You could also checkout the map functions in purrr
https://blog.rstudio.com/2015/09/29/purrr-0-1-0/

Comment: Have a look at `tibbles` and `purrr` package.

Comment: Can't you just use something like `sapply(myDocs$drive_resource, "[[", "webViewLink")`?

Comment: This works @Alexis - if you post it as the answer I'll accept it...

Answer (score 0):

as said in the comments `map` from `purrr` would work. Here is an alternative using a function I use often: `rvest::pluck`.

```
#
N <- 10
sample_list_data <- lapply(1:N, function(i){
  list(other = runif(3),
       webViewLink = sample(letters, 1))
})
myDocs <- data.frame(drive_resource = matrix(sample_list_data))

library(rvest)

myDocs$url <- unlist(pluck(myDocs$drive_resource, "webViewLink"))

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark("old" = {
  myDocs$url0 <- NA
  for (i in 1:nrow(myDocs)) {
    myDocs$url0[i] <- myDocs$drive_resource[[i]]$webViewLink
  }
}, 
"new" = {
  myDocs$url1 <- unlist(pluck(myDocs$drive_resource, "webViewLink"))
})

myDocs
```